# Getting the value of an object instead of its location in memory

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I'm studying OOP in Python and I'm making a game with 5 dices. I made the `Dado` object to represent my dices and the `GeraDado` object to actually create the `Dado` object. If I create an object such as `d1 = GeraDado()` I can print its value using the `d1.valor()` method but if I try to append its value to a list or dictionary it returns `None`. If I do `print(d1)` it returns the object's location in memmory and not the value. How can I make it return the `d1 = GeraDado()` value instead of using the `d1.valor()` method, that just prints the value on screen?

```
from random import randint

class Dado:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.__valor = valor

    def valor(self):
        print(self.__valor)
        
class GeraDado:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dado = Dado(randint(1,6))

    def dado(self):
        self.__dado.valor()

d1 = GeraDado()
print(d1)
```

Comment: the `append` method on a list returns `None` as long as you see it at the end of the list, it functioned properly. You want to override the `__str__` method to return what you consider a "proper" string representation of your class. By deafult python outputs the location in memory along with some other metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Dado.valor` and `GeraDado.dado` methods only print the value of the die, they don't actually return it, instead, make them return the value using the `return` statement:

`Dado.valor`:

```
def valor(self):
    return self.__valor
```

`GeraDado.dado`:

```
def dado(self):
    return self.__dado.valor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two little suggestions:

```
class Dado:
    # ...
    def valor(self):
        return self.__valor  
        # 1. return stuff!
        # Don't fall in love with print. It's just a debugging side-effect
      

class GeraDado:
    # ... 
    def dado(self):
        return self.__dado.valor()  # 1. again: return!

    # 2. implement a __str__ method. 
    # This is your class's representation that is used by print
    def __str__(self):  
        return str(self.dado())

>>> d1 = GeraDado()
>>> print(d1)
1
```